# How can I get Node.js to create a simple database in MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**This is the code I've been using in Node.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/vegesDB', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

const vegeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

const Vege = mongoose.model("Vege", vegeSchema);

const vege = new Vege({
  name: "Potato",
  rating: 9,
  review: "Very versatile vegetable"
});

vege.save();
mongoose.connection.close();
```

**And this is the error message I get in the console:**

```
C:\Users\85569\Desktop\Neptune Pluto\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:153
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `veges.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\85569\Desktop\Neptune Pluto\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:153:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Node.js v18.6.0
```

For the record, I'm using MongoDB version v5.0.9
I have no other problems with the version of MongoDB I have loaded on my laptop.  It's when I try to use Mongoose that everything goes haywire.  Any information about the latest super-duper updated way of using Mongoose for this purpose would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried using variations of the above code suggested by other programmers on other sites and, to date, I haven't found one of them that works.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong is your code. Just add `await` before `vege.save();`.

Like this;

```
await vege.save();
```

**Update:**

Ok so I played with your code and found out commenting `//mongoose.connection.close();` these lines makes the code work.

I think since nodejs is asynchronous the save() method takes time so before that finishes the `mongoose.con.close()` hits and close the connection so that you get the error

**Update 2:**

This is the code I worked;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/vegesDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

const vegeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});

const Vege = mongoose.model("Vege", vegeSchema);

(async () => {
    const vege = new Vege({
        name: "Potato",
        rating: 9,
        review: "Very versatile vegetable"
    });

    await vege.save();
})()
// mongoose.connection.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but it's still not working for me even after placing "await" before "vege.save();

Comment: I have update the answer please check it.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, even when I comment out the mongoose.con.close().  I get this error:

C:\Users\85569\Desktop\Neptune Pluto\FruitsProject\app.js:23
await vege.save();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: I added the code I worked pl check

Comment: Still not working for me, even after testing your code in Update 2.  I get an error message in the console.  I'll post it.

Comment: C:\Users\85569\Desktop\Neptune Pluto\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:153
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

Comment: MongooseError: Operation `veges.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\85569\Desktop\Neptune Pluto\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:153:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Comment: I guess you may don't have installed mongodb in your machine ?

Comment: Yeah, I've got mongodb installed on my machine.  It works when I play with it directly in the Mongo shell.  It only fails if I try to do anything using Node.js and Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

save() is a method on a Mongoose document. The save() method is asynchronous, so it returns a promise that you can await.

When you create an instance of a Mongoose model using new, calling save() makes Mongoose insert a new document.

In your case, you missed the **await** part so the mongoose failed to save the data.

to solve this issue use `await vege.save()`

(i.e)

```
const Vege = mongoose.model("Vege", vegeSchema);

const vege = new Vege({
  name: "Potato",
  rating: 9,
  review: "Very versatile vegetable"
});

await vege.save();
```

More about save() can be found [here](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/save)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it's still not working.  Even after adding await before vege.save() I'm getting an error in the console.